# How to have matter modules and services in android emulator

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

I have selected pixel 6 in as android emulator. It doesn't contain matter modules and services. (Verifying from steps in https://developers.home.google.com/matter/verify-services).

How can I have matter modules and services in android emulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no support for Matter modules and services in Android Emulator. You will have to work with a physical android device to get the matter modules and services so as to make it compatible with matter devices.